# What is going on with this SQL PK/FK error?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, key, schema

I am having an issue with my SQL code. I am creating two tables, one named Orders_For, and another named Result. Result should pull the "Date," and "Time" from Orders_For as foreign keys. These foreign keys from Orders_for are also Result's primary keys. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

I am getting Error:

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
> 00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"

Here is the code that is giving this and the result:

Code (Easier to understand in images):

```
--ORDERS_FOR(OrdersForDate, OrdersForTime, PhysicianID, TestNumber, TestName, PatientID)

CREATE TABLE ORDERS_FOR(
    
OrdersForDate VARCHAR(50),
    
OrdersForTime VARCHAR(50),
    
O_PhysicianID CHAR(5),
    
O_TestNumber CHAR(5),
    
O_TestName VARCHAR(45),
   
O_PatientID CHAR(10),
    

CONSTRAINT Orders_ForPK_ok PRIMARY KEY(OrdersForDate,OrdersForTime,O_PhysicianID,O_TestNumber,O_TestName,O_PatientID),
    CONSTRAINT Orders_ForFK FOREIGN KEY(O_PhysicianID)
        REFERENCES PHYSICIAN(PhysicianID),
    CONSTRAINT Orders_ForFK_tol FOREIGN KEY(O_TestNumber,O_TestName)
        REFERENCES TEST(TestNumber,TestName),
    --CONSTRAINT Orders_ForFK FOREIGN KEY(O_TestName)
      -- REFERENCES TEST(TestName),
    CONSTRAINT Orders_ForFK_toll FOREIGN KEY(O_PatientID)
        REFERENCES PATIENT(PatientID)
    );
        
--RESULT(Date, Time, Result)
CREATE TABLE RESULT(
   ResultDate VARCHAR(50),
   ResultTime VARCHAR(50),
   ResultGiven VARCHAR(100),
   CONSTRAINT ResultPK_o PRIMARY KEY(ResultDate,ResultTime),
   CONSTRAINT ResultFK_tol FOREIGN KEY(ResultDate,ResultTime)
        REFERENCES ORDERS_FOR(OrdersForDate,OrdersForTime)
  --CONSTRAINT ResultFK_n2 FOREIGN KEY(ResultTime)
       --REFERENCES ORDERS_FOR(OrdersForTime)
    );
```

And here is the Script Output:

```
Table ORDERS_FOR created.
```

> Error starting at line : 86 in command -
> CREATE TABLE RESULT(
> ResultDate VARCHAR(50),
> ResultTime VARCHAR(50),
> ResultGiven VARCHAR(100),
> CONSTRAINT ResultPK_o PRIMARY KEY(ResultDate,ResultTime),
> CONSTRAINT ResultFK_tol FOREIGN KEY(ResultDate,ResultTime)
> REFERENCES ORDERS_FOR(OrdersForDate,OrdersForTime)
> --CONSTRAINT ResultFK_n2 FOREIGN KEY(ResultTime)
> --REFERENCES ORDERS_FOR(OrdersForTime)
> )
>
> Error report -
> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
> 02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
> *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
> *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS catalog view

These are also attached in the  images.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir5SZ.jpg)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoC2s.jpg)

Comment: Also, I did not include "TEST" table because I did not think it was revelant to this problem. But if it helps I will include it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: And what is not clear in the error description? And why you post ORA-00955 when later you show another error?

Comment: On a side note: Your data types are inappropriate. Why split date and time at all and use strings for this? I suggest `order_datetime DATE` instead. ( `DATE` is Oracle's inappropriate name for a datetime.)  In Oracle you should not use `VARCHAR` by the way, but `VARCHAR2` instead. And never use `CHAR`, always use `VARCHAR2` instead. Working with `CHAR` can be very hard and is prone to errors, because blanks get added that you must be aware of when writing your queries. Oracle themselves recommend not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key references a primary (or unique) key. I.e. for a row in the child table there is exactly *one* related row in the parent table.

You want a foreign key on `(ResultDate, ResultTime)`. But this is not a primary or unique key in the parent table `ORDERS_FOR`. There can be many rows for the same date and time, because the two columns are only *part* of the primary key.